# Fetching data from estimates in zoho invoices

Tags: zoho

i'm trying to fetch data from estimates module in Zoho Invoices but it keep giving me error of invalid url passed, the url im using is:
https://invoice.zoho.com/api/GET/estimates/{$estimate_id}?authtoken={$auth}&organization_id={$org_id}

and the response im getting is:

```
<Response status="0">
<Code>5</Code>
<Message>
<![CDATA[ Invalid URL Passed ]]>
</Message>
</Response>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with it, or some other method to get the task done. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to use is invalid.

The URL should be like

```
https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/estimates/$estimate_id?authtoken=$auth_token&organization_id=$org_id.
```

Here's the [API documentation](https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/estimates/#get-an-estimate) that would guide you.